# Android XmlPullParser get value between tags

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I have something like this in XML:

```
<trkpt lat="-32.577000" lon="-71.443764">
            <ele>2.204529</ele>
            <time>2015-12-27T12:35:45Z</time>
```

I can get lat and lon with

`XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
parser.getAttributeValue(0);
parser.getAttributeValue(1);`

But how can I get the value stored between the "ele" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use [getText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getText()) on the current element. From the documentation

```
Returns the text content of the current event as String.
```

Of course you have to move the parser to the correct element calling `next ()`. From the documentation:

```
Get next parsing event
```

Comment: You're right, I just needed to check the tag using something like "if("ele".equals(Parser.getName()) and then use getText. Thank you.